# What would happen raft-log-gc-size-limit is larger than region-split-size in TiKV

Tags: tikv

I have a TiKV setup it has a `region-split-size` as 96MB, which is the default and `raft-log-gc-size-limit` is 144MB. How does it impact the tikv cluster. Since it is mentioned that `raft-log-gc-size-limit` should be 3/4th of `region-split-size`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may waste space for storing raft logs and waste network traffic to restore Raft state.

A Region is managed by a Raft group, and it splits when it's data exceeds `region-max-size`, eg, Region [a,e) may be split into several Regions [a,b), [b,c), [c,d), [d,e) and the size of [a,b), [b,c), [c,d) are around the `region-split-size`. So TiKV assumes size of a snapshot is around the `region-split-size` too.

An out of date peer restores state either by snapshot or by raft logs. Raft logs are always preferred. There are two possible outcomes if we store too many raft logs (> `region-spilt-size`):

1. Waste network traffic to restore state,
2. Waste space to store raft logs, older raft logs may never be fetched and sent.

Comment: Is it fine to reduce `raft-log-gc-size-limit` on a running cluster and do a rolling restart?

Comment: Generally, we should not reduce `reduce raft-log-gc-size-limit` as it may cause too many snapshots. For now, we need to do a rolling restart to apply the change.